# What kind of websites are best suited for Google's AMP (Accelerated Mobile Pages)

Tags: performance, mobile-website

I recently learnt about Google's [AMP](https://www.ampproject.org/) project. I currently work on an online classifieds application, that has some client side JS. I understand that it's mostly content sites like Blogs that use AMP.

My question is this - are there any advantages or is there any need, for other web applications(e-commerce etc.) to sign up for AMP?

Answer (score 6):

AMP pages (like you mentioned) are great for content heavy site like blogs and news sites. The MAIN advantage to AMP is that it will load your page much faster on a mobile device. You would have two version of each page, the regular desktop version and then it's AMP equivalent.

AMP pages have tons of restrictions which allow the page to load much faster as all of the layout calculation are done before any rendering to the screen, but the limitations are why AMP pages don't work well for e-commerce.

No external authored JS files are allowed unless AMP-IFRAMED. Custom css can be placed in your AMP page but must be included into an AMP custom style tag, cannot contain any wildcard selectors (*) and is limited to 50k.

All request from an AMP page must be made via HTTPS as well.

These are just a few of the restrictions and I suggest if you're at all interested in pursuing AMPing your site, read everything you can first. Here is a good page that will answer a lot of HOW TO questions. [TURN your AMP up to 11](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/02/everything-about-google-accelerated-mobile-pages/).

Good luck!